# How do I authenticate a .NET Core Generic Host daemon app to AzureAD with MSAL or ADAL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have created an app registration for the app in AzureAD. The app runs on prem and needs access to a Key Vault and my App Service REST API. All the accesses work fine when run under my Visual Studio credentials. But when deployed it will fail w/out the app authenticating. But, what libraries and code are required to authenticate the app?

I have looked at the following:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2 (does not use generic host)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-configuration (doesn’t work with generic host)

Current Code:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{    
    // Logging
    try
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Handle
    }
}

private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config => { config.AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_"); })
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => { AddConfigurationProviders(config); })
               .ConfigureServices(AddServices)
               .UseSerilog();
}

private static void AddConfigurationProviders(IConfigurationBuilder config)
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false);

    var configuration = config.Build();

    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
            $"https://{configuration["keyVault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
            keyVaultClient,
    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());            
}
```

Comment: Go through entire [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication), pay attention to the parts [`Running the application using service principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) and do not skip any reference documentation mentioned. Then update your question with exact error message / stack trace.